# Как проверить дату создания фала

Tags: файлы, php, дата

Пытаюсь сначала узнать дату создания файла и потом сравнить с текущей датой. 
Сделать условие, если файл создали не позднее 2х недель, тогда:

пока написал определение даты создания файла, но почему то выводит всегда одно и то же, хотя должны быть разные даты. пример вывода: `01.01.1970 03:00:00`

```
echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s.", filemtime($out_1));
```

Подскажите как правильно узнать дату и сравнить с текущей ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
 $filetime = filectime("test.txt");
 $time = microtime(true);
 $endtime = $time - $filetime;
 echo "Файл был создан $endtime секунд назад.";
```

filemtime — Возвращает время последнего изменения файла